# How to display range of date and reference from another Subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, join

i have a list of activities table..now i want to get the count of activities created per day

eg. result would be:

```
Date          Count
01/10/2016    100
02/10/2016    20
03/10/2016    3000
```

Hours of searching from the net, this is the working code:

```
DECLARE @start_date DATE = '2016-10-01';
DECLARE @end_date DATE= '2016-10-10';

WITH    AllDays
        AS ( SELECT   @start_date AS [Date]
               UNION ALL
              SELECT   DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
            FROM     AllDays
               WHERE    [Date] < @end_date ),
       PartitionCount
       AS (select count(*)      AS [Count]
          from Activities act
          where CAST(act.CreatedDate AS DATE) = '2016-10-01')
SELECT distinct [AllDays].[Date], [PartitionCount].[Count]
FROM   AllDays, PartitionCount, Activities
ORDER BY [AllDays].[Date]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

This will give this result:

```
Date          Count
01/10/2016    100
02/10/2016    100
03/10/2016    100
```

However, this one only get the count for the day **2016-10-01**.

So I tried to change this part of the code so that the activity created date will be equal to the Date column of AllDays and will get the count of activities for that specific date.

```
AS (select count(*)     AS [Count]
from Activities act
where CAST(act.CreatedDate AS DATE) = [AllDays].[Date])
```

But, this will give the error

> "The multi-part identifier could not be bound"

I would really appreciate your help on how I can proceed with this and get the desired result:

```
Date          Count
01/10/2016    100
02/10/2016    20
03/10/2016    3000
```

Example table looks like this

```
Table: Activities

ID Title        CreatedDate         
1 Activity1 2016-10-03 10:00:00.000
2 Activity2 2016-10-03 11:30:00.000
3 Activity3 2016-10-03 14:00:00.000
4 Activity4 2016-10-03 14:30:00.000
5 Activity5 2016-10-04 10:00:00.000
6 Activity6 2016-10-05 11:00:00.000
7 Activity7 2016-10-06 10:00:00.000
8 Activity8 2016-10-07 11:00:00.000
```

Comment: You need to provide data also from which you want to calculate this result.

Comment: add sample data with table strucure.

Comment: Hi @CoderofCode,  I only have a simple table which looks similar to this: 
Table: Activities

Title  CreatedDate   
Activity1 2016-10-03 10:00:00.000
Activity2 2016-10-03 11:30:00.000
Activity3 2016-10-03 14:00:00.000
Activity4 2016-10-03 14:30:00.000
Activity5 2016-10-04 10:00:00.000
Activity6 2016-10-05 11:00:00.000
Activity7 2016-10-06 10:00:00.000
Activity8 2016-10-07 11:00:00.000

Comment: Please add expected result set for given data. And also check out my answer and let me know if thats what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you want `Count` for rows for each day. For that you can do `Group By` on each day between given range and then also `COUNT` to get what yo want as below,

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, date)) As Date, COUNT(*) As Cont 
FROM #temp
WHERE date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
GROUP By DATEADD(DAY,0, DATEDIFF(DAY,0, date))
```

Comment: Very fast thinker @CoderofCode, I'll try your code :) Thank you

Comment: It took me almost the whole day just to figure out how to do it. And, you did it in a blink of an eye @CoderofCode 

It works!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try This simple Example,
create procedure and pass 2 parameter StartDate,EndDate   and Execute SP.

```
  declare @StartDate Date ='2016-10-01';
    declare @EndDate Date ='2016-10-10';

    select CreatedDate,COUNT(*) Count from Activities 
    where Convert(Date,CreatedDate) between @StartDate and @EndDate
    Group by CreatedDate
```

Comment: This will not give proper output as you need to separate out the time from date otherwise different time for same day rows will get counted differently.

Comment: Thank you @TejashRaghav Let me try this as well :)

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't return the total count of activities per day. It returns something like this:   

2016-10-03 16:19:00.000 1
2016-10-10 11:37:14.000 1
2016-10-10 06:57:29.000 1

Comment: yeah,you are right but i'm checking it with only Date type.